# How do I visualize and modify the content of a pickled function?

Tags: python, pickle

I need to use a pickled data processing function that was not written by me and I therefore do not know its content/structure. When I load it, a ModuleNotFound Error occurs:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.preprocessing.label'
```

I assume that the error occurs because the pickled object is trying to import a module named 'sklearn.preprocessing.label', which doesn't exist. I have tried to downgrade my sklearn version but that didn't work either. ¨

If I knew what the pickled object was doing I could simply make my own function to replace the function within the pickled object. In order to do that I would have to visualize the function contained within the pickled object, or remove the `import sklearn.preprocessing.label`.

Comment: There is no "function contained within the pickled object".  All the pickle recorded was the name of the function, and the module it was contained in.

Comment: do you know when the pickle file was created ?

Comment: I think your best bet is to iterate through the minor versions of sklearn (e.g. pip install sklearn==0.19).  Keep note of your current version so you can re-install later ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sklearn.preprocessing.label` was available in scikit-learn version 0.21 and below: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/0.21.X/sklearn/preprocessing